# include multi color labels in d3 v4

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to assign different color for the tick label texts in a same axis of a d3 chart based on a condition,

```
var input = ["Vegetable", "Grains", "Fruits", "Ham"]
var ch = yaxis.selectAll("text");
                
                ch.style( "fill", function()    {
                    for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++)   {
                        if(input[i].indexOf('Fruit') != -1) {
                            return "black";
                        }
                        else    {
                            return "blue";
                        }
                    }
                })
```

where my y axis will have 4 ticks from the input array.
but i can see, it applies only once and does not consider the else condition.

Is there any way, where i can have different color label texts in the same axis?

Update:
I was able to achieve this by selecting all the axis ticks and then changing its style,

````
.style( "fill", function(d) {
            for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
                if(d.indexOf('*') == -1)    {
                                            return "black";
                                        else    {
                                            return "red";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I correctly got your idea, but if you want the ticks that contains 'Fruit' to be fill by black and others for blue, the logic of your function is wrong.

You don't have to iterate the input array, just pass the data binded in each text into the function, and check whether it contains the 'Fruit' string.

If this is not what you mean, please provide your intenion more clearly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>      
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

let input = ["Vegetable", "Grains", "Fruits", "Ham"]

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var y = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([height, 0])
          .padding(0.1);
          
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

y.domain(input.map(function(d) { return d; }));

// add the y Axis
let yaxis = svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "yaxis")
              .call(d3.axisLeft(y));


let ch = yaxis.selectAll("text");
                
ch.style( "fill", function(d)    {
    // console.log(d);
    if(d.indexOf("Fruit") !== -1) return "black";
    else return "blue"

})

</script>
</body>
```